# random bundler installation path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

after bundle install i'm getting

Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./Imlib2

sometimes it changes to another gem name like

Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./delayedjob

any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like bad config file in .bundle removed it and it's fine now.

Answer (score 0):

also you can fix it with `bundle install --system` command